# Why is my clip-path not working when it's source is an svg?

Tags: css, svg

I'm following the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example.3A_Clipping) on using css `clip-path` property to apply an `svg clipPath` to an `HTMLElement`. But for some reason, it doesn't work for me, not in div's and not in images.

In the documentation, it says you can easily clip an element with this code:

```
<style>.target { clip-path: url(#c1); }</style>
<svg:svg height="0">
  <svg:clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <svg:circle cx="0.25" cy="0.25" r="0.25" id="circle"/>
    <svg:rect x="0.5" y="0.2" width="0.5" height="0.8"/>
  </svg:clipPath>
</svg:svg>
```

And I've tried that, but it doesn't work. The `clip-path` property works with predefined methods like polygon() and ellipse() but it won't work with a linked svg.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qyxjL7y/3/) illustrating my problem, hopefully you can find my mistake :)

Comment: What are you testing this on? Chrome has a limitation currently that it won't clip html content with url clip paths. Also the content above is xhtml (it is namespaced) so it won't work in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put your `clipPath` in `defs` tags. Use `foreignObject` to import the HTML elements that needs to be clipped and apply inline `clip-path` for maximum browser support.

```css
#kitten {
  width: 250px;
}
#kittenReplica {
  width: 250px;
  height: 187.5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500px" height="187.5px">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <circle cx="0.25" cy="0.25" r="0.25" id="circle" />
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.2" width="0.5" height="0.8" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#path)" width="50%" height="100%">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tzPv43g.jpg" id="kitten" class="clipped" />
  </foreignObject>
  <foreignObject x="250" clip-path="url(#path)" width="50%" height="100%">
    <div id="kittenReplica" class="clipped"></div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still, one question, isn't it a little weird to put your html inside your svg? If I then want to place the kitten inside let's say another div, should I place the whole svg?

Comment: Thank you very much, one last thing, why is the width of the foreign object 50%? I mean where do you get those values from. I'm sorry, I'm new to the whole svg thing :)

Comment: @Rou - It's because if you notice I've set `svg`'s `width` to `500px` and your kitten and `lighblue` elements are `250px` each. That's the reason behind setting it to `50%`. Btw, here is an example if you want to put the `svg` in a container: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/vf8o7dvj/

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice that hahaha, thank you man, you get the god almighty green tick (I'm also very new to stackoverflow, don't know exactly what that gives you).

Comment: Hey, @chipChocolate.py sorry to bother you again, but I need to ask you, before your implementation, with the css `clip-path` property, I could animate it pretty easily, can I animate it with your version? What I mean is, transitioning between path #1 and path #2 was as simple as `.path2{ transition:2s;clip-path:url(#path2)}`

Comment: It's funny but when I use the path's I gave you it doesn't animate them, it just alternates them hahaha, does it have to do with some svg syntax or what?

Comment: I figured hahaha, so.. I made the path's in adobe illustrator, any idea how to convert them? I'm sorry I'm taking so much of your time.

Comment: Honestly I don't have a clue what this means: `M238,89.5l103.1,137.8v223l-185.1,12.2L39.7,115.2l60.8-64.9L238,89.5z`(path1) or this `M238,89.5l226.1,152.7l-73,362.2L62.7,546.3l-23-431.1l60.8-64.9L238,89.5z`(path2) and even if I had, still don't know how to convert them or what makes them unusable D:

Comment: By the way the reason it didn't animate it's because it needs to have the same commands in both paths (you can only vary values), although I'm looking at a complete animation guide and hopefully find an answer to add to this question :)

Comment: [Source](http://codepen.io/noahblon/blog/an-intro-to-svg-animation-with-smil) `The paths need to have the same number of vertices.` in case you wanted to know more haha

Comment: Looking for this solution for ever. <foreignObject> instead of applying clip path url to element via css.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that you were using elements with the "svg" namespace prefix, but not defining the svg namespace.  If you remove the "svg:" from each element, it works.

For example, change `<svg:svg ...>` to `<svg ...>`.

If you look at the original Firefox example you copied from, you will see that the svg namespace is defined in the `<html>` element: `xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.

Below is a version of that sample that works on Firefox and Chrome.

And [here is an updated version of your fiddle that works.](http://jsfiddle.net/8qyxjL7y/7/)

```css
body {
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:30px;
}

p {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1em;
}

b {
    outline:1px dotted blue;
}

.target {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#c1);
    clip-path: url(#c1);
}
```

```html
<p class="target" style="background:lime;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</p>
 
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/tzPv43g.jpg" id="kitten" class="target" />


<svg height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <circle cx="0.25" cy="0.25" r="0.25" id="circle"/>
            <rect x="0.5" y="0.2" width="0.5" height="0.8"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! But in my fiddle I did put the prefix :(

Comment: Yo are right. Sorry.  I've updated my answer with the correct explanation.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry if this doesn't belong here, but can you tell me how would one animate a clip-path transition? I thought it would be as simple as changing the `clip-path` property with a transition applied to the object but it's not haha

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question for that.  You may need to explain what sort of animation you are after.